# Translate animation has no effect

Tags: android, android-animation

I want my view to move from bottom right corner of my  layout to the center. I only have a textView inside a RelativeLayout and wrote a simple code to test it but did not work.

This is my animation XML;

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%" 
    android:fromYDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="50%p"
    android:toYDelta="50%p" 
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

This is my layout file;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="x" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the related part of the Activity;

```
    x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Animation translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
            R.anim.viewanimation); 
    x.startAnimation(translate);
```

The problem is, the textView "x" doesn't move. I have read that specifying `%p` in XML file makes it relative to the parent. Since I want my view to move from its original position to center of screen, I set the "from" and "to" values as `0%` and `50%p`. I observed that when I remove `%p` attributes and make it move from something like from `0%` to `-100%`, it moves correctly. So relative positioning does not seem to work here. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved. Relative values should be negative as follows;

```
android:toXDelta="-50%p"
android:toYDelta="-50%p"
```

Because positive values move the view out of the layout. So, `%0p` values correspond to the right and bottom corner of the layout.